# Is there a way to know the number of children with FBConnect

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

All is the question, is there a way to know the number of children of an user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can request the `user_relationships` permission and use https://graph.facebook.com/me/family to look for and count son/daughter records.

Answer (score 1):

With the `user_relationships` permission you can make a call to 
`https://graph.facebook.com/FB_UID/family`
Then you can parse all the results and extract only the values that have the property and value

```
{
"name": "Lix",
"id": "4815262342", 
"relationship": "brother/sister"
}
```

You can use a regular expression to match both entries.

Comment: Brothers and sisters are not one's children, they're one's siblings. :-)

Comment: oops. :P oh well... same solution,  different regex. ;)

Answer (score 1):

'Family' is an array containing the user's family members, listing the user ID and relationship for each member.